# trigger onlick event where element has no .click() function

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, mouseevent, onclicklistener

i want to automate a buttonclick on a webpage. But the element i want to click has no normal `.click()` function.
I know that the element i want to click is:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("smart-button-svg")[0]
```

but when i do:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("smart-button-svg")[0].click()
```

i get

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0].click is not a function
```

looking into the js code (i dont have much experience with javascript)

i found this section

```js
[a("svg", {
                        staticClass: "smart-button-svg",
                        attrs: {
                            viewBox: "0 0 100 100",
                            preserveAspectRatio: "xMinYMin meet"
                        },
                        on: {
                            click: this.handleSmartButtonClicked
                        }
```

Can i trigger the function `handleSmartButtonClicked` with a simple command like

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("smart-button-svg")[0].handleSmartButtonClicked()
```

For reference here is a larger part of the section which also includes the function definition of `handleSmartButtonClicked`

```js
var _e = t("VU/8")(ve, ze, !1, function(e) {
                t("5dNk")
            }, null, null).exports,
            ge = t("/ocq"),
            Le = {
                name: "SmartButton",
                props: {
                    text: {
                        type: String,
                        default: ""
                    },
                    color: {
                        type: String,
                        default: ""
                    },
                    disabled: {
                        type: Boolean,
                        default: !1
                    }
                },
                computed: {
                    fillColor: function() {
                        return this.color || "#00AF9A"
                    }
                },
                methods: {
                    handleSmartButtonClicked: function() {
                        this.disabled || this.$emit("buttonClicked")
                    }
                }
            },
            Ne = {
                render: function() {
                    var e = this.$createElement,
                        a = this._self._c || e;
                    return a("div", {
                        staticClass: "smart-button tile",
                        class: {
                            disabled: this.disabled
                        }
                    }, [a("svg", {
                        staticClass: "smart-button-svg",
                        attrs: {
                            viewBox: "0 0 100 100",
                            preserveAspectRatio: "xMinYMin meet"
                        },
                        on: {
                            click: this.handleSmartButtonClicked
                        }
                    }, [a("g", [a("circle", {
                        staticClass: "circle-back",
                        attrs: {
                            r: "50%",
                            cx: "50%",
                            cy: "50%",
                            fill: this.fillColor
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of try to click in a class, You can look for a ID inside or even near that class that also can trigger it, then use the click() on it.

> document.getElementById('loginbtn').click();

Comment: Thanks, for the tip. There actually is a id near that class. this div is wrapped around the svg div.  

When i do:

document.getElementById("homeViewSmartButton").click()

 i get: 

undefined
and the action the button is supposed to do does not happen

Answer (score 0):

In the end i found that i can click this "invisible" button in the following way.

I find the coordinates of the button and then i click on those coordinates... i dont like it but it works.

for some reason this did not work with the previously mentioned element

`document.getElementsByClassName("smart-button-svg")[0]`

but with an "circle" element contained inside it and its visually on the same position.

`document.getElementsByClassName("smart-button-svg")[0]`

```html
<svg data-v-73587c28="" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="smart-button-svg">
  <g data-v-73587c28="">
    <circle data-v-73587c28="" r="50%" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="#00AF9A" class="circle-back"></circle> 
    <text data-v-73587c28="" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" dy="0.3em">Start</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

```js
function getOffset(el) {
  const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    left: rect.left + window.scrollX,
    top: rect.top + window.scrollY
  };
}

function clickmouse(x, y)
{
    var ev = new MouseEvent('click', {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true,
        'screenX': x,
        'screenY': y
    });

    var el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);

    el.dispatchEvent(ev);
}

var coord = getOffset(document.getElementsByClassName("circle-back")[0]);
clickmouse(coord.left,coord.top),PageLoadTime);
```